# Biblatex change punctuation between authors in multiple citations

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I use `biblatex` package. I have a problem with changing multiple citations punctuation.

I want use such commands as `\cites` and `\parentcites` follows:

```
\cites{AuthorYYYY,AuthorYYYY,AuthorYYYY}
```

I have in output:

> Author1 YYYY; Author2 YYYY; Author3 YYYY.

But I want to have:

> Author1 YYYY and Author2 YYYY
>
> Author1 YYYY, Author2 YYYY, and Author3 YYYY
>
> Author1 YYYY, p. 1-3, Author2 YYYY, and Author3 YYYY, pp. 4 and 12-14

How do I change it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the general punctuation between consecutive citations that are passed to the same cite-command by changing `\multicitedelim`. So, something like `\renewcommand{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}` should change your output to

> Author1 YYYY, Author2 YYYY, Author3 YYYY

for `\cites{AuthorYYYY,AuthorYYYY,AuthorYYYY}`.

Now you even want a different treatment with 'and' in case of two citations and comma between all citations, except the last where it should be 'and' with Oxford-comma in case of more than two citations. I think this is not easily possible, because seemingly biblatex does not distinguish between the delimiter for the last item and all other items separately, as it does for the author-name and list delimiters.

Answer (score 5):

I'm late for the party, but I think now `biblatex` allows you to do that.

Consider the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cites{glashow,herrmann}

\cites{glashow,herrmann,kastenholz}

\cites[1-3]{glashow}{herrmann}[\ppno~4 and~12--14]{kastenholz}
\end{document}
```

which prints:

> [image]

If we redefine `\multicitedelim` we can make it print different delimiters, depending on the number of citations (stored in the `citetotal` counter) and the number of the current citation (stored in the `citecount` counter):

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{%
  \iflastcitekey
    {%
      \ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifnumgreater{\value{citetotal}+\value{multicitetotal}-1}{2}}
         or test {\ifnumgreater{\value{lastcitetotal}+\value{citetotal}}{2}}
       }
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
      \addspace\bibstring{and}\space
   }
   {\addcomma\space}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citetotal}}{\value{citecount}}
   {\setcounter{lastcitetotal}{\value{citetotal}}}
   {}%
}
```

The above definition checks if the current citation key is the last one in the comma separated list using `\iflastcitekey`. If it's not the last citation, just print `\addcomma\space` (*i.e.*, `,␣`). Otherwise, if it's the last key, we check if the expression `\value{citetotal}+\value{multicitetotal}-1` or `\value{lastcitetotal}+\value{citetotal}` are greater than two, and if they are, print a `\finalandcomma` and then `\addspace\bibstring{and}\space` in all cases (`,␣and␣`).

The first expression is less or equal the total number of citations in the multi-cite command, so if there are multiple citations it will ensure the `\finalandcomma`. This expression will only fail in the case `\cites{one,two}{three}`, where `multicitetotal` is two and `citetotal` is 1 when `three` is being processed. In this case the expression evaluates to 2 and the `\finalandcomma` is *not* printed, whereas it should.

To work around that exception I added a <s>bodge</s> temporary counter which stores the previous `citetotal`. In the case of the exception, `lastcitetotal` will be 2 and `citetotal`, 1, and their sum will be larger than 2 so the `\finalandcomma` will be printed.

Adding that definition to our example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newcounter{lastcitetotal}
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{%
  \iflastcitekey
    {%
      \ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifnumgreater{\value{citetotal}+\value{multicitetotal}-1}{2}}
         or test {\ifnumgreater{\value{lastcitetotal}+\value{citetotal}}{2}}
       }
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
      \addspace\bibstring{and}\space
   }
   {\addcomma\space}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{citetotal}}{\value{citecount}}
   {\setcounter{lastcitetotal}{\value{citetotal}}}
   {}%
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\cites{glashow,herrmann}

\cites{glashow,herrmann,kastenholz}

\cites[1-3]{glashow}{herrmann}[\ppno~4 and~12--14]{kastenholz}
\end{document}
```

we get:

> [image]

Comment: `biblatex` has the test `\iflastcitekey` that should also take into account multicites.

Comment: I should also note that the `p.~` in `[p.~1--3]` is superfluous (since `biblatex` automatically adds the "p."/"pp." in postnotes if they contain only a page range) and that in `[pp.~4 and~12--14]` I would prefer `[\ppno~4 and~12--14]` (here the page detection will yield false because of the `and`, so we need to ask for the "pp." explicitly).

Comment: Getting closer ... `\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{%
  \iflastcitekey
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{citetotal}+\value{multicitetotal}-1}{2}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
    {\addcomma\space}}` works almost except for `\cites{glashow,herrmann}{kastenholz}` because I couldn't find a way to count the total across several multicites. Hence I used `\value{citetotal}+\value{multicitetotal}-1` which should be `\leq` the actual total.

Comment: @moewe Wow, I left for lunch and when I came back ;) Hm... What if I remember the last `citetotal` and use that to check for that exception? Like [this](https://pastebin.com/SKYaW4cB)? Seems to work, what do you think? Oh, and if I replace `[p.~1--3]` by `[1--3]` or `[1-3]` I get `pp. 1–3` instead of `p. 1–3`. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes, "pp." instead of "p." is expected (at least for English texts). Traditionally, "p." stands for "page" while "pp." stands for the plural "pages". Since `1-3` is a page range it would be prefixed with "pp." and not "p.". (Other languages might be different, in German we use "S." for both singular and plural.)

Comment: Finally managed to wrap my head around the `lastcitetotal` idea. I'm pretty much convinced that it should do the right thing here. Of course the additional counter is not pretty, but I'm not sure if it is possible to get a real 'overall citecount' ready...

Comment: @moewe Oh, I agree, it's a very clumsy approach. I think it should be possible to have the “overall citecount” as well, mainly because when the first `\multicitedelim` is inserted we already know how much is `multicitetotal`, so it means `biblatex` already scanned the list of `[<postnote>]{<citation>}`s once, it just didn't count the citations _inside_ that list. Of course I might be reading something wrong here. When I have some time I'll take a look to see if I manage to do something nicer than `lastcitetotal`, meanwhile I'll point that in my answer. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I think an 'overall citecount' would be possible (we just have to remember the previous and reset it at the beginning). But usually a citecount is accompanied by a citetotal and I can't think of a way to get 'overall citetotal' to work. As far as I understand, `biblatex`'s multicite works roughly as follows: First it collects and counts the multicite groups (that is what `multicitecount` is for), then each multicite group is passed to one normal cite command. A cite command first counts the keys it gets (for `citecount`) and then starts its work. ....

Comment: ... This would mean that at the first constituent cite of a multicite we know how many multcites there are going to be, but not how  many keys there are going to be in each. That is only counted once the constituent cite is actually executed.

Comment: @moewe I think I managed to implement an “overall citecount” in biblatex (not extensively tested, though :-). [The code](https://pastebin.com/raw/Gp8vHAGr) ([and the diff against the one in TL2018](https://pastebin.com/wWKQVWRy)) and [a test document](https://pastebin.com/raw/vCCWBb1j). If you think it's worth it I'd be happy to add a pull request to the `biblatex` repo :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into this. I have to admit that I don't quite understand all the tricks you pulled off. I ran a few tests, though, and found two issues: (1) It seems that the new counters leak in case one uses only a single `\cite` command. (2) The trick to count the entries per multi-cite group does not drop duplicate entries (if they are indeed dropped). An example is at https://gist.github.com/moewew/df9eb6e4f730350084b9a3fb371621a9

Comment: @moewe Hm. I imagined that the smuggling thingy would cause trouble... And I completely overlooked the duplicate entries. I'll need some time to investigate this. Perhaps over the weekend. I'll get back to you when I find a solution :-)

Comment: I'd have probably just used global assignments and would reset them as necessary to avoid the smuggling (which I don't know a lot/anything about). But the more tricky issue is properly counting the number of items per 'group'. It feels a bit wrong to count things at the early stage that would be required to get the correct `overallcitetotal`, especially because the counting will be repeated at a later processing step. But that seems to be the only way ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92067/discussion-between-phelype-oleinik-and-moewe).

Comment: I answered on https://gist.github.com/moewew/df9eb6e4f730350084b9a3fb371621a9. Your name did not `@`-autocomplete, so I'll just ping you here.